# 1and1 and simple htaccess redirect fails

Tags: linux, .htaccess, cloud, web-hosting

we need to create a very simple htaccess file on 1 and 1 linux hosting
that will redirect any request for "localfile.html" to "localfile.php" both 
located in the same directory as htaccess file. 
Showing content from localfile.php and a URL(file name) localfile.html
(Only managed to make 1 and 1 htaccess work as a complete redirect for
domain A to domain B, not what we need, and 1 and 1 apparently does not
provide support for scripting..)

Code was:
I'v tried= RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^localfile.html$ localfile.php [L] =and got 404

UPDATE:
There are limitation of what you can do with 1and1 htaccess file

Comment: Good luck with that...

Comment: You didn't include the relevant code from your .htaccess file.  How do you expect us to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly. To rewrite the URL path `localfile.html` to `localfile.php`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^localfile.html$ localfile.php [L]
```

If you want to redirect, add an [`R`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag

```
RewriteRule ^localfile.html$ localfile.php [R,L]
```

Comment: When I create .htaccess with ONLY following:

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^localfile.html$ /localfile.php [L]

and in a browser enter appropriate 
path for localfile.html  - i get 404 error, 
but I can access - localfile.php using 
browser just fine.. so 1and1's server IS 
trying to do "Something..."

Comment: @W-W What is the appropriate path? And where is the .htaccess located? If `localfile.php` is not in the root directory, then this won't work, of course.

Comment: All 3 files:
"localfile.php" , "localfile.html", ".htaccess"
Are all located in the same subfolder of the 
"campaignA" - i.e.: h t t p ://subdomain.domain.com/campaignA/

Comment: @W-W Then you must remove the leading slash in the substitution.

Comment: Hi Olaf, I'v tried=     RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^localfile.html$ localfile.php [L]    =and got 404.. it might be something specific to 1and1 Linux hosting?

Comment: @W-W It works in my test environment, so I don't know. Maybe some file access permissions? You can try adding the `R` flag, to see if it redirects at all.